# Rails one-to-many: Validate field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, activerecord, psql

Suppose I have two classes

```
    class student < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :books
    end

    class Book < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :student
    end
```

Each book will have a boolean variable `read` indicating if the book has been read or not. Each student can only read one book. If any of a student's book is marked as read, his other books cannot be read anymore.

Is there a PSQL or active-record validation to allow this constraint to happen?

Specifically, `book.update_attributes!(read: true)` will do a check on other associated books. DB constraints would be much preferred.

Much thanks!

Update to problem statement:

read becomes a timestamp read_at and `book.update_attributes!(read_at: Time.zone.now)` will do a check if the student has read any other books previously.

Comment: So when a record is created in the Book table, `read` would be set to `false`, and updated to `true` when that book is read... once any book has been read, any attempt to change a different book's `read` value to `true` should fail, is that correct?

Comment: Books are created with read default to false and update to true when read. any attempt to change a different book of the same student's read value to true should fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an unique partial index on a boolean `read` field and integer `student_id` field where read is equal true

```
add_column :books, :read, :boolean, null: false, default: false
add_index :books, [:student_id, :read], unique: true, where: "read=true"
```

In Book model add unique validation that will works only when `book.read == true`

```
validates :read, uniqueness: { scope: :student_id }, if: -> (book) { book.read }
```

Comment: This validates uniqueness. Do you know if there is anything does allow_false: true and allow_nil: true?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my answer and test it.

Comment: `validates :read, uniqueness: { scope: :student_id }, if: 'read.present?'` this works as well I think.

Comment: Update to this problem: what if read becomes a timestamp `read_at`. One student can still only read one book. Specifically, book.update_attributes!(read_at: Time.zone.now) will check if any other books were read by that student.How should the schema look like?

Comment: Try to change `where: "read=true"` to `where: "read_at IS NOT NULL"`. Probably need to add custom validation to check uniqueness.

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of :student_id, conditions: -> { where.not(read_at: nil) }` this seems to work. Not sure about db constraint though.

Comment: `add_index :books, :student_id, unique: true, where: 'read_at IS NOT NULL', algorithm: :concurrently`